# How to locally link pages in worldpress

Tags: wordpress

We are currently building a site on our server that will eventually take over a current site. The problem we are running into is that all of our hyperlinks will change once we transfer over to the new site. Is there a way to link pages without hard coding in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use mod_rewrite to rewrite your URL from the old format to the new format. You might start at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html. If you search on mod_rewrite, you will be able to find lots of examples and tutorials to help you.